# Reports 11g fails when copy/past a text field

Tags: oracle11g, oracle11gr2, oraclereports

I have a problem in reports 11g that when working on a report if I try to copy/past any field (text, data even a line) reports crashes, is it a common problem or there's a problem with the installation. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a MetaLink document - ID 1395965.1 - regarding this problem which states that the fix is to make sure that you install the 32-bit versions of the Oracle Fussion Middleware software rather than the 64-bit ones, even on 64-bit platform.

For more knowledge about the problem you can visit the following link.
https://pitss.com/us/2015/01/19/copyingpasting-in-reports-builders-layout-editor-causes-reports-builder-to-freeze/